# ClassNotFoundException returned for all plugins

Tags: windows-7, java

I am trying to use a Java applet (any Java Applet), but I always get a messages saying "Error. Click for details".

When I do so, the pop-up says:

Application Error

ClassNotFoundException

jreVerification.class

When I click the "Details" button, all I see is the following:

```
Java Plug-in 10.7.2.10
Using JRE version 1.7.0_07-b10 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\razumny
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
```

I am running Windows 7 Professional, and am up to date on patches.

The problem occurs in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer, regardless of what Java Applet I am running.

The error I quoted above came from here: http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre

I have attempted the following to rectify the issue:

- Uninstall and reinstall Java
- Uninstall Java, reboot, install Java
- Uninstall Java, delete all registry entries, reboot, install Java

In addition, I have run Malware and Virus scans, none of which have shown anything of relevance.

At this point, I am at my wit's end, and so, I turn to you.

Comment: there likely is no silver bullet.... do these troubleshooting steps help? => http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/java-is-installed-on-my-windows-7-computer-but-ie/b198bf41-3bc8-41b3-98e2-e9e6373bfd21   =or= https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2431218&tstart=0

Comment: OK, let's see...

Comment: Thanks for that @michael_n, I have had a look at both links, though for the second one I was met by: The specified thread [2431218] was not found.

Here are my results for the first link: No thirdparty firewall installed, Windows Firewall disabled. No thirdparty AV solution installed. Internet Explorer security settings are set to default. The issue persists even with a newly created User account.

I have posted to that thread too, but any help you can give me would be appreciated.

Comment: those threads are still in google search results (search: jreVerification.class windows 7), and my browser history, but now the thread's mysteriously gone. (Maybe Oracle is gc'ing the internet...) If I recall, the idea goes something like (1) make sure all old JVM's are _completely_ uninstall/deleted, (2) check ( http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp ), (3) download/install "windows offline" (i.e, full) for win x86 (32-bit) even if using 64-bit windows ( http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp ) (4) check version again (above). See also: http://java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml

Comment: having same problem. trying uninstalling previous versions of java see if it helps.

Comment: did not work. There are a few anti-virus and download manager but turning them off did not work.

Comment: In my case, it looks like Elluminate is the culprit. I have it installed in order to follow tutorials at the Open University, and Java has not functioned correctly since I installed the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have more than one jre installed on your system path.

Some applications install their own jre - they're too lazy to check if you already have one or they need a specific version, and then insert that jre into the path variable.

In a console (at the command line), type PATH and look for entries with "jre" in them. Or just search your Program Files for java.exe (if memory serves).

Edit your path to only reference the jre that you yourself installed.