# ClassNotFoundException returned on every Java applet on the internet

Tags: java

I am trying to use a Java applet (any Java Applet), but I always get a messages saying "Error. Click for details".

When I do so, the pop-up says:

> Application Error
>
> ClassNotFoundException
>
> jreVerification.class

When I click the "Details" button, all I see is the following:

```
Java Plug-in 10.7.2.10 
Using JRE version 1.7.0_07-b10 
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 
User home directory = C:\Users\Beth
---------------------------------------------------- 
c:   clear console window

f:   finalize objects on finalization queue

g:   garbage collect

h:   display this help message

l:   dump classloader list

m:   print memory usage

o:   trigger logging

q:   hide console

r:   reload policy configuration

s:   dump system and deployment properties

t:   dump thread list

v:   dump thread stack

x:   clear classloader cache

0-5: set trace level to <n>
```

---

I am running Windows 7 Professional, and am up to date on patches.

The problem occurs in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer, regardless of what Java Applet I am running.

The error I quoted above came from here: http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre

but it happens on every java applet website.

I have attempted the following to rectify the issue:

Uninstall and reinstall Java

Uninstall Java, reboot, install Java

Uninstall Java, delete all registry entries, reboot, install Java

Tried All versions of Java JRE and JDK.

In addition, I have run Malware and Virus scans, none of which have shown anything of relevance.

Comment: You say "every java applet website", have you tried any local java applications?  Have you tried uninstall and reinstalling Chrome or Firefox?  Do you have any "Click to play" settings or extensions affecting Java?

Comment: I tried installing runescape locally, would that count? It didn't work, gave me the rs2applet.class but same error.

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing chrome and firefox, I even went as far as installing IE to try it.

Right now I am just using Google Chrome, all the other browsers have been uninstalled. Does chrome have a click to play setting? Other than that, I don't think any other settings or extentions are currently interfering with it.

Comment: Hang on a minute; did you already post the exact same question?  or copy-paste?  This looks identical: http://superuser.com/questions/469707/classnotfoundexception-returned-for-all-plugins

Comment: I pasted this on StackOverflow, a guy that was there told me to try here, since it wasn't coding.

The super user question isn't me, but it looks like he has the same issue, although I don't have the program Elluminate installed as he did, I have no idea what is causing my problem. :(

Comment: Couple of things you could try: use [JavaRa](http://singularlabs.com/software/javara/) to completely remove Java then reinstall.  Or try turning off any third party firewalls temporarily.

Comment: @ColinPickard I will try that now, I have no firewalls installed at the moment, added java to the exceptions list on the firewalls as well even though they aren't enabled.

Comment: @ColinPickard Okay I tried that, I am no longer getting the error, but now I just get a grey screen when I try use the Java applets O.o

Comment: @ColinPickard still no luck :C

Comment: One last idea; remove with JavaRa, then use [the offline installer](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/windows_offline_download.xml) to install